# Ethernet switch timeout after 3min ~50seconds using Micrel KSZ8895MQXC evaluation board

Tags: ethernet, switch

I am trying to test throughput and ping delay on a chain of Micrel KSZ8895 chips. Unfortunately I am running into the issue that they stop sending data 3 minutes and ~50 seconds after boot. I have tried to access the registers through SPI but when I set the evaluation board to SPI mode it fails to send any packets at all. Any ideas as to why the switch would fail every time after a set amount of time?

Answer (score 0):

you need to set bit 0 in SPI register 0 or 1. In SPI or I2C mode the chip only starts after setting this bit